# Cisco 2948G - No Config Terminal

Tags: networking, cisco

Recently I inherited a "**WS-2948G**" and the **configure terminal** command is missing. What am I missing?

I think this may be some kind of distributed switch that I'm not completely competent with but there so many models of 2948's that I'm not certain. Let me know if you need commands ran.

### show version

```
Console> show version
WS-C2948 Software, Version NmpSW: 7.6(2)
Copyright (c) 1995-2003 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
NMP S/W compiled on Jun 25 2003, 23:00:25
GSP S/W compiled on Jun 25 2003, 17:11:56

System Bootstrap Version: 6.1(5)

Hardware Version: 2.2  Model: WS-C2948  Serial #: JAB04100JWL

Mod Port Model              Serial #              Versions
--- ---- ------------------ -------------------- ---------------------------------
1   0    WS-X2948           JAB04100JWL          Hw : 2.2
                                                 Gsp: 7.6(2.0)
                                                 Nmp: 7.6(2)
2   50   WS-C2948G          JAB04100JWL          Hw : 2.2

       DRAM                    FLASH                   NVRAM
Module Total   Used    Free    Total   Used    Free    Total Used  Free
------ ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ----- ----- -----
1       65536K  38095K  27441K  12288K  10438K   1850K  480K  308K  172K

Uptime is 0 day, 5 hours, 45 minutes
```

### show system

```
Console> show version
PS1-Status PS2-Status
---------- ----------
ok         none

Fan-Status Temp-Alarm Sys-Status Uptime d,h:m:s Logout
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- ---------
ok         off        ok         0,00:53:48     20 min

PS1-Type          PS2-Type
----------------- -----------------
internal 120AC    none

Modem   Baud  Traffic Peak Peak-Time
------- ----- ------- ---- -------------------------
disable  9600   0%      0% Wed Jan 4 2017, 17:40:53

Power Capacity of the Chassis: 1 supply

System Name              System Location          System Contact           CC
------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ ---
```

### show boot

```
Console> show boot
BOOT variable = bootflash:cat4000-k8.7-6-2.bin,1;
CONFIG_FILE variable = bootflash:switch.cfg

Configuration register is 0x2
ignore-config: disabled
auto-config: non-recurring
console baud: 9600
boot: image specified by the boot system commands
```

What am I missing here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you runned "enable" before to try configure terminal ?

Comment: What do you mean *the `configure terminal` command is missing*? Do you get an error when attempting to run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That switch uses Catalyst-OS (CatOS), not IOS. It uses `set` commands to configure it. You are basically in the configuration mode if you are in enable mode. This switch has been EoL since November of 2009. It may be difficult to find documentation.

Comment: Well thank you for the clarification, I'll update my post so others can find this issue better.



**As a follow-up: This switch is a Layer 2 switch I imagine, is there a command to find the exact model number? I want to find the manual.**

Comment: I believe that the model can be found with the `show version` command: `WS-C2948`.